# コンピュータシステムの理論と実装におけるハードウェア記述言語の構文解析について

Tags: java

[コンピュータシステムの理論と実装――モダンなコンピュータの作り方](http://www.oreilly.co.jp/books/9784873117126/) (原書名: The Elements of Computing Systems: Building a Modern Computer from First Principles) のハードウェア記述言語 (HDL) で記述されたプログラムに応じた回路を生成するアプリケーションを作成しています。

これを作成するにあたり現在構文解析を行っているのですが、これを行うにあたり参考になるサンプルプログラムなどあれば教えていただきたいです。

使用言語は現在Javaを使用しています。

Answer (score 2):

Javaのパーサージェネレータと言ったら[ANTLR](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR)でしょう。文法の定義ファイルから、パーサーのソースを出力してくれます。

メジャーな言語の文法は大概実装されています。VHDL, Verilogともあります。

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/vhdl

Answer (score 1):

JavaCC を調べてみてはいかがでしょう。

http://codezine.jp/article/detail/367

Answer (score 0):

`VHDL`, `Java`, `Parser` というキーワードで検索すれば見つかるものですが、以下のプロジェクトにVHDLのパーサが実装されているようです。

https://github.com/gburdell/parser/tree/master/src/parser/vhdl

参考になるかもしれません。

他にも以下の様なプロジェクトが見つかるのですが、こちらはダウンロードするのにユーザレジストレーションを要求されるので、ちょっと敷居が高いと感じるかもしれません。

http://home.wtal.de/software-solutions/vhdl-parser/

Comment: このソースはANTLRで生成されたものですね。